# SDカードの総容量や使用量を取得するには？

Tags: spresense

arduino IDEで開発しています。
使用しているSDカードの容量情報を取得したいのですが、どのようなプログラムを書けば情報を取得できるでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arduino環境からでも`#include <sys/statfs.h>`をインクルードすれば
`statfs`関数(https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/LDP_man-pages/man2/statfs.2.html)を使って
次のコードでSDカードの全体容量や空き容量を取得することができそうです（できました）。

```cpp
#include <sys/statfs.h>
#include <SDHCI.h>
SDClass SD;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  /* Initialize SD */
  while (!SD.begin()) {
    ; /* wait until SD card is mounted. */
  }

  struct statfs statfsbuf;

  if (0 == statfs("/mnt/sd0", &statfsbuf)) {
    printf("Total: %lld [MB]\n", statfsbuf.f_bsize * statfsbuf.f_blocks / 1024 / 1024);
    printf("Free : %lld [MB]\n", statfsbuf.f_bsize * statfsbuf.f_bfree / 1024 / 1024);
  }
}

void loop()
{
}
```

ご参考まで。

Answer (score 1):

使用している量ということであれば、次のようなコードはどうでしょうか？

```
#include <SDHCI.h>
SDClass SD;

uint32_t read_directory_size(File& dir) {
  uint32_t dir_file_size;
  while (true) {
      File myfile = dir.openNextFile();
      if (!myfile) break; // ファイルがない場合処理終了
      if (myfile.isDirectory()) {
        dir_file_size += read_directory_size(myfile);
      }; 
      Serial.println(String(myfile.name()) + ":" + String(myfile.size()));
      dir_file_size += myfile.size();
      myfile.close(); 
  }
  dir.close();
  return dir_file_size;
}

void setup() {
  uint32_t total_file_size = 0;
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!SD.begin()) { Serial.println("Insert SD card"); }
  File sd_root = SD.open("/");
  total_file_size = read_directory_size(sd_root);
  Serial.println("Total size:" + String(total_file_size));
}

void loop() {}
```

追記：
差されたSDカードのボリュームを知りたい場合は、あまりエレガントなやり方ではないですが `/proc/fs/usage` の情報を読み込めばおおよそのボリュームサイズが分かります。（もっと良い方法があるとは思いますが、、、）

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <SDHCI.h>
#define IOBUFFERSIZE 256
SDClass SD;
char buff[IOBUFFERSIZE];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!SD.begin()) {Serial.println("insert sd card");}
 
  memset(buff, NULL, IOBUFFERSIZE*sizeof(char));
  int fd = open("/proc/fs/usage", O_RDONLY);
  if (fd < 0) {
    printf("file open error\n");
    return;
  }
  int readnbytes = read(fd, buff, IOBUFFERSIZE);
  if (readnbytes <= 0) {
    Serial.println("fail to read /proc/fs/usage");
    return;
  }
  close(fd);
  String fs_usage = String(buff);
  fs_usage.trim();
  Serial.println(fs_usage);

  int str_cnt = 0;
  int index = 0;
  String strs[100];
  memset(strs, '\0', sizeof(String)*100);
  while (fs_usage.length() > 0) {
    int index = fs_usage.indexOf(' ');
    if (index == -1) {
      strs[str_cnt++] = fs_usage;
      break;
    } else {
      String str  = fs_usage.substring(0, index);
      str.trim();
      strs[str_cnt++] = str;
      fs_usage = fs_usage.substring(index+1);
      fs_usage.trim();
    }
  }
  // for debug
  for (int i = 0; i < str_cnt; i++) {
    Serial.println(String(i) + ": \"" + strs[i] + "\"");
  }
  // get available size of SD card (vfat)
  String str_sd_size = strs[9];
  String unit;
  int str_len = str_sd_size.length();
  switch(str_sd_size[str_len-1]) {
  case 'K': unit = "KB"; break;
  case 'M': unit = "MB"; break;
  case 'G': unit = "GB"; break;
  }

  uint32_t sd_size = str_sd_size.substring(0, str_len-1).toInt();
  Serial.println("SD card volume : " + String(sd_size) + unit);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

Comment: 使用している量も調べたいのですが、全体の容量を調べ、そこから残りの容量を算出したいです。

Comment: 差されたSDカードの容量を知りたいということですね。エレガントなやり方ではないですが追記してみました。ご覧ください。